# Best web UI framework for Visual-Studio-like layout management + component instantiation

Tags: visual-studio, web, ide

Have a look at [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFWTI.png) of Visual Studio resizing / merging(into tab groups) / instantiating new sub-panels in the main window.

I'm trying to create a single page web application that is very similar to this. I want to be able to create new "panels" and drag/drop/group them into place. Ideally the framework should be as flexible as Visual Studio is.

Does anything like this exist or I will have to do everything myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like all of them are listed here in the first FAQ:

http://golden-layout.com/faq/

> ….this type of layout paradigm is referred to as "docker" (not to be confused with the virtualisation containers). Examples for frameworks that implement the docker paradigm are PhosphorJS, wcDocker or dockspawn A similar approach (without the re-ordering) is provided by jQuery Layout and ExtJS